# How to split table into two tables in one transaction or query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table "profiles" with these columns: "id", "name", "surname", "email", "avatar".

I want to create table "media" which will contain columns "id" and "path".

After that I want to create column "profiles"."avatar_id" and migrate data by this rule: each value of "profiles"."avatar" must be inserted into "media" ("media"."id" is autogenerated), returning id must be written into "profiles"."avatar_id" in the same row.

It should be executed in one query, transaction or procedure, and I want to use only postgres functionality.

I tried to rename "profiles" to "profiles_old", create new "profiles" with "avatar_id" but without "avatar". Then run something like:

```
INSERT INTO profiles(id, "name", email, surname, avatar_id)
SELECT id, "name", email, surname, (INSERT INTO media(origin) VALUES(profiles_old.avatar) RETURNING id) FROM profiles_old;
```

...but `SELECT` doesn't support subquery `INSERT`. Maybe I should use procedure?

I am using Postgres 9.4.9. I tried a transaction and temp tables. I cannot understand how to insert each row of one table into another table and update the same row of first table with returned id? My code:

```
BEGIN; 
ALTER TABLE profiles DROP CONSTRAINT profiles_pkey; 
ALTER TABLE profiles RENAME TO profiles_old; 
CREATE TABLE profiles ( 
id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), 
"name" character varying(255), 
email character varying(255), 
surname character varying(255), 
avatar_id uuid NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT profiles_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) ) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE ); 
ALTER TABLE profiles OWNER TO app;
INSERT INTO profiles(id, "name", email, surname, gender, avatar_id) SELECT id, "name", email, surname, (INSERT INTO media(origin) VALUES(profiles_old.avatar) RETURNING id) FROM profiles_old; 
DROP TABLE profiles_old; 
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Is it a strict 1-1 relationship? I.e. will every row in existing table correspond to 1 row in the new table? And vice versa? If yes, why do you need/want the `media.id` to be autogenerated? Why can't you just copy the `profile.id` values and get rid of the `avatar_id` and all this complexity?

Comment: Because media will contain not only avatars but another media records which not related with profiles. I solved my problem with Node.js because I didn't find how to do this by SQL or postgres script.

Answer (score 4):

> I cannot understand how to insert each row of one table into another
>   table and update the same row of first table with returned id

You don't have to use an intermediate table. It can be done in one statement, with a writeable CTE:

```
WITH t as
 (INSERT INTO media(origin) SELECT DISTINCT avatar FROM profile RETURNING id,origin)  
 UPDATE profile SET avatar_id=t.id FROM t WHERE avatar=t.origin;
```

(assuming that `media.id` is automatically set by its DEFAULT clause).

Or the same as two statements in a transaction, using a different form of update:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO media(origin) SELECT DISTINCT avatar FROM profile;
UPDATE profile SET avatar_id=(SELECT id FROM media WHERE profile.avatar=media.origin);
COMMIT;
```

If you know that `profile.avatar` is unique, `DISTINCT` can be omitted, otherwise it's required.